# angularjs binding: which is preffered {{a}} {{b}} or {{a + " " + b}}?

Tags: angularjs, binding

Is it recommended to have a single expression with concatenation inside or use multiple expressions, one for each variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both these expressions are interchangeable in *most* situations and they generate the same DOM structure. So choosing between them is largely a matter of taste.

However, there is a very subtle difference between the two which comes into play with `a` and `b` are not primitive objects.

If the objects `a` and `b` are not primitive, the form `{{a}} {{b}}` will call the `toJSON` function on them and display the result (usually with the quotes). Doing `{{a + ' ' + b}}` will first convert both of them to string and then concatenate the string, always returning a primitive string which will be rendered without quotes.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yKSBj8DaD9Exn9fDNkzc?p=preview

Another nice oddity is that `ng-bind` calls the `.toString` function instead of the `.toJSON`, which has [lead to issues](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/764).

Comment: Any difference performance-wise if I have tons of such expressions ?

Comment: @redben I don't think so. I'll run a check with jsperf later.